# Every free module is projective

Tags: abstract-algebra

Could someone explain me why free $R$-modules are projective, using the universal property of free modules to show the lifting property defining projective ones?

Comment: The solution at the duplicate does exactly that.

Comment: I am sorry, I found the answer in the duplicate

Comment: there is also not really ever a reason to use the abstract-algebra tag alone. In this case you should also have used the modules tag at the very least.